# Tildes reemplazadas por signos de interrogación al migrar de Tomcat 7 a Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, codificación, tildes

He tenido que migrar mi aplicación web de tomcat7 a tomcat8 y, aunque en un principio todo funcionaba bien, he localizado un error en la codificación de las tildes y las ñ.

Pero más allá de que pudiera ser un error de codificación de UTF-8 o ISO-8859 (que ya he probado), me llama la atención que el error se produce incluso en los logs de la propia aplicación, es decir, entre mis logs me encuentro cosas como "comprobando conexi?n" en lugar de "comprobando conexión".

Si desde un formulario introduzco tildes también me las cambia por el caracter "?". También cambia las "ñ" y "¿" por "?".
Es como si desde que he hecho el cambio a tomcat8 todas las tildes se cambiarán por "?", y no solo en los xml, porque lo que más me extraña es que lo haga incluso en los logs.

Cosas que he probado:
Según he visto, tomcat 8 trabaja por defecto con UTF-8 y tomcat7 no, así que he probado a modificar el fichero de configuración "server.xml", usando tanto `URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"` como `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`, y ninguna de las dos cosas ha funcionado.

¿Pudiera ser que, al crear el proyecto en Eclipse, me lo codifica de una manera, y al subir la aplicación al servidor, éste tenga otra codificación y por eso me esté dando ese error?
He encontrado esto referido a un error parecido, aunque en este caso con NetBeans: "*Esto es debido a que la codificación que utiliza Netbeans por defecto para los proyectos, es UTF-8, mientras que la que utiliza Windows en español es, ISO-8859-1 (o el superconjunto Windows-1252), como podemos ver en las propiedades del proyecto:*"

¿Alguien sabe si puede deberse a eso?

Comment: Dices que pasa en los logs. ¿El texto en el código aparece correctamente?

Comment: Pues verás, cuando entro en la aplicación, todo el texto que estuviera bien (que proviene de ficheros xml) se ve bien, pero en el momento que hago alguna inserción o edición de datos, el xml se cambia y todos las tildes y ñ se sustituyen por "?". Eso me llevó a pensar que era por la codificación UTF o ISO 8859-1, pero lo que me extraña muchísimo es que hasta en los logs también todas las tildes se sustituyen por ? desde el principio.

Comment: Me refiero al código fuente, en los ficheros Java. ¿Se ven bien las tildes?

Comment: Si, en el códifo fuente en java se ven bien.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado.

El problema es que el "file.encoding" en el servidor (que puede verse mediante la llamada a `System.getProperty("file.encoding"))` era *ANSI_X3.4-1968*, que es el que pone los caracteres mal.

Probé a poner en el código `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")` pero no funciona.

Hay que modificar las opciones de arranque del tomcat. En concreto, en el fichero */bin/catalina.sh* tendremos que añadir lo siguiente:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF8 ${CATALINA_OPTS}"

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas encontrado solución. No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.